# Create an OR conditional statement from a list of options

Tags: google-sheets

I want this: input in A1 and output in A2.

input: `0` output: `AND (A=0)`

input: `0,1` output: `AND (A=0 OR A=1)`

input: `0,1,2` output: `AND (A=0 OR A=1 OR A=2)`
etc...

I've tried a few things with the `REPT` function but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me when I tested it with your sample strings:

```
="AND(A="&SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," OR A=")&")"
```

It basically replaces each comma with the or part of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose A1 is "1,2,3"

```
="AND (" & JOIN(" OR ",ARRAYFORMULA("A="&split(A1,","))) & ")"
```

where

- `split(A2,",")` splits A1 into an array {1,2,3}
- `arrayformula("A=" & split(...))` convert the array to {"A=1", "A=2", "A=3"}
- `join(" OR ", arrayformula(...))` joins the array with " or " inbetween value, so you have "A=1 OR A=2 OR A=3"
- `"AND (" & join(...) & ")"` should be self-explanatory

Comment: sorry. my question isn't clear. I'm going to reword it